# Как открыть новое окно, чтобы старое осталось активным? C# forms

Tags: c#, winforms, процесс, окно

Нужно открыть новое окно приложения, чтобы с предыдущим можно было взаимодействовать. Нигде не смог найти информацию про это. 
Многие предлагают просто для каждого окна создавать отдельный проект. 
Но тогда встаёт новая проблема: при сворачивании основного окна другие не будут сворачиваться тоже. 
Конечно можно просто убивать их процессы но это не то, что мне нужно.

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает метод `Show()`? Он не блокирует окна, и с ними можно взаимодействовать и работать.

Comment: @Yami предполагаю, что много исполняемого кода в основном потоке.

Comment: Перехватывайте событие сворачивания и сворачивайте дочерние окна. Аналогично разворачивайте

Comment: @DNS Как я перехвачу событие, когда дочерние окна "заслоняют" (блокируют доступ) к главному и другим окнам. Фактически активным остаётся только верхнее окно, остальные "замораживаются"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откройте его в новом потоке [STA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.apartmentstate(v=vs.110).aspx) правда взаимодействие усложнится.

---

```
private void MyForm()
{
    Form frm = new Form();
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

---

```
private void ShowMyForm()
{
    Thread th = new Thread(MyForm);
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
    this.Activate();
}
```